# Not working pages with custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-wordpress-pages

I defined custom taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'my_tax',
    'post',
    array(
        'label' => __('My Tax'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'mytax'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'capabilities' => array(
            'name' => _x('My Tax', 'taxonomy general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('My Tax', 'taxonomy singular name'),
            'menu_name' => __('My Tax')
        )
    )
);
```

And configuration of permalink is custom and looks: `/%my_tax%/%postname%/`. Everything works correctly for **posts** like:

```
example.com/my_defined_tax1/post_no_1
example.com/my_defined_tax1/post_no_2
example.com/my_defined_tax2/post_no_3
```

But if I have **page**:

```
example.com/sample_page/
```

I receive 404 error. What I must do for fix this issue?

Comment: need more information here! Have you got index.php etc in your theme?

Comment: What exactly info you need? This looks like custom taxonomy not correct rewrite urls (can't find pages). When I'm not using custom permalink everything work correctly.